# CSS variables not working in media queries using Sass

Tags: html, css, sass, css-variables

I have a problem when changing css varibables via media queries. 
Styles of media query 768px are not applied.

```
   :root {
      --profile-picture-size-w: 9rem;
      --profile-picture-size-h: 9rem;
      --profile-picture-border: 1px solid #1e96a9;
      --profile-box-backgound-size: cover;
      --profile-box-p: 20px 0;
      --article-dateInfo: 3px;
    }
 .component{
  #main_content {
    .scrollbarContent{
      article#profile {
        .profileBox {
          background-size: var(--profile-box-backgound-size);
          padding: var(--profile-box-p);
            .profilePicture {
              width: var(--profile-picture-size-w);
              height: var(--profile-picture-size-h);
              .photo {
                border: var(--profile-picture-border);
              }
            }
        }
        article#dateInfo {
          padding: var(--article-date-info);

        } }

      }
    }
  }

@media all and (min-width: 768px){
  --profile-picture-size-w: 5.5rem;
  --profile-picture-size-h: 5.5rem;
  --profile-picture-border: 5px solid #1e96a9;
  --profile-box-backgound-size: 100% 38%;
  --profile-box-p: 20px 0 0 0;
  --article-date-info: 0;
  :host {
    height: 77vh;
  }
}
```

this also not working :

```
     @media all and (min-width: 768px){
         :root {
          --profile-picture-size-w: 5.5rem;
          --profile-picture-size-h: 5.5rem;
          --profile-picture-border: 5px solid #1e96a9;
          --profile-box-backgound-size: 100% 38%;
          --profile-box-p: 20px 0 0 0;
          --article-date-info: 0;
              }
          :host {
            height: 77vh;
          }
        }
```

But when placing this media query inside a component it works but this time in less than 768px properties are not applied. So strange problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example within your question? I have used a part of your code and it appears to work without any problem: https://jsfiddle.net/zza6624e/

Comment: Do you realise you have set `min-width`, which means it only works on large screens instead of small screens? Because it seems you are setting smaller margins on larger screens. Try using `max-width` instead.

Comment: @Randy . It is not because of that. Variables are not applied before and after breakpoint.

Comment: @Terry Thank you. I tested there , it seems there is a problem with package node-sass which compiles sass to css

Comment: No problem: some of the comments in this thread might also help you: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1943